# Friend with own class template with other template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, friend

Is it possible to declare your own class template with other template parameters as a friend?

```
template<class T, class... Ts>
class A {
    template<class U> friend class A<U, Ts...>;    //compile error - C3772  'A<U>': invalid friend template declaration 
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class T, class... Ts>
class A {
    template<class U, class... Us> friend class A; //here you go
};
```

There is no need to specify template arguments after `A`

Comment: the problem there is that there is a new parameter pack introduced(Us). I only want the first parameter of A to be different. Is that possible too?

Comment: @Philinator I'm pretty sure it's not possible in current standard.

Answer (score 2):

A partial specialisation of a class template cannot be declared a friend. Only a (full) specialisation, or an entire class template. If you really need to befriend all `U` specialisations, you need to befriend the entire template:

```
template<class U, class... Us> friend class A;
```